# Open webpages generated by restdocs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I want to display static pages using Spring Boot. I tried this configuration:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert" version "3.3.2"
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

group = 'com.example'

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

ext {
    restdocsVersion = '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    snippetsDir = file('src/static/docs')
}

configurations {
    asciidoctorExtensions
}

dependencies {
    asciidoctorExtensions "org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-asciidoctor:$restdocsVersion"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.6.3'

    implementation 'io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:1.0.15'


    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.5.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.0'
    testImplementation "org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-restassured:$restdocsVersion"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-test'
    testImplementation('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.0'
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

asciidoctor {
    configurations "asciidoctorExtensions"
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}

jar {
    dependsOn asciidoctor
    from ("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
        into 'static/docs'
    }
}
```

I placed several .adoc files under this file location:

[image]

I started the project as a Spring Boot project but when I open `http://localhost:8080/docs/index.html` I get white label error:

Do you know how I can serve this content as web pages?

Comment: Your build configuration means that Asciidoctor's HTML output is included in your application's jar file. Unless you're running that application using that jar, the HTML isn't going to be available to be served as a static resource.

Comment: is it possible to serve content as ascii web pages directly from `/src/static/docs/index.adoc` as web pages?

Comment: There's nothing that I know of that supports that out of the box. You could write something that uses AsciidoctorJ to render the `.adoc` file as HTML and you could then return that HTML in an HTTP response. That would make sense if you have dynamic content, otherwise I think it would be more efficient to render at build time and serve the resulting static HTML directly.